# Jquery animate () function does not work with the css height property

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to create a click event for the image to automatically change the height to 100% while the other images to a height of 0. You can see it working live at the website www.nhadatsonnghia.com nhà đất gò vấp .

Below is the code I have tried. Can someone help me? Thanks very much.

```
$('.post-header .desc-image-list .thumb .natural-thumbnail').click(function () {
        $(this).find('img').each(function () {
            var image_url_in_first_list = $(this).attr('src');
            $('.post-header .desc-image-list .full .natural-thumbnail').each(function () {
                if ($(this).css('height') == '100%') {
                    $(this).animate({
                        height : 0
                    }, 100, function () {
                        $('.post-header .desc-image-list .full .natural-thumbnail').each(function () {
                            if (image_url_in_first_list === $(this).find('img').attr('src')) {
                                $(this).animate({
                                    height : "100%"
                                }, 100);
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Please check if the css is being overwritten

Comment: Oh thanks @VictorZyonTiangson I fixed this issue by change to 600px on desktop and mobile! Have a nice day bro!

Comment: No problem man! I'm glad you could solve your problem.